# Update missing data in SSAS Multidimensional cube

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, mdx, cube

I have a SSRS report which is missing the phone call data for a single date (example; 06/04/2021). The data source for the report is using a SSAS MDX query. I have explored ways to backdate the SSAS cube but couldn't figure out how to do so. I have added a measure to the SSAS cube but haven't backdated the missing data yet. Anyone has any idea how to populate the cube with the specific date?

Comment: Maybe look in the source of your cube if that specific date is populated

Comment: Are you asking how to update the cube with data that has been refreshed?  Usually if you want to bring new data into a cube you would need to process the cube.  If you data source (database) has been updated with the value when you process the cube the data should pull through.